# irb's behavior for escaping double quotes

Tags: ruby, irb

Inside the irb:

```
"\'"
```

returns `"'"`, however

```
"\""
```

returns `"\""`, ie, it's the same as the input, without escaping the double quote. Using it with puts works as expected, but why does it not work when it is tried in this manner?

Comment: "without escaping the double quote" - you already have it escaped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

irb is working perfectly. You can't expect it to output `"""`.

By definition:

> an escape character is a character which invokes an alternative
>   interpretation on subsequent characters in a character sequence.

In your expected output `"""` clearly middle `"` has a different interpretation. Hence its getting escaped.

To make things clearer:

```
"\""
#=> "\""
puts "\""
# "
```

Comment: For even more confusion: `"\"".inspect`

Comment: @D-side, if I'm not wrong the extra backslashes are added as a result of the escape sequence for the backslash itself?

Comment: @Projjol that's right. Every syntax-significant symbol is escaped with a preceding backslash.

Comment: @Projjol is there anything else you are looking forward to be answered in this question?

Answer (score 1):

[IRB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html) uses `Object#inspect` by default after a statement execution to display the result of statement.

In case of [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-inspect), the documentation says

> Returns a printable version of str, surrounded by quote marks, with
>   special characters escaped.

```
irb(main):001:0> "\""
=> "\""
irb(main):002:0> '"'
=> "\""
```

When starting IRB, you could pass `--noinspect` option, in which case, irb will use `to_s` to print result.

For example, if we had a class:

```
class Test
    def to_s
        "#{self.class} instance"
    end
end
```

Default IRB:

```
irb(main):003:0> Test.new
=> #<Test:0x00000002ad7fa8>
```

With `irb --noinspect`

```
irb(main):002:0> Test.new
=> Test instance
irb(main):003:0> "\""
=> "
irb(main):004:0> '"'
=> "
irb(main):005:0>
```